# Wired Connection to LAN, but no Internet

Tags: 12.04, networking, internet, wired

In my college we have a LAN network through which we can access the Internet and DC++. This requires registration of a mac address which I have done.

Initially the network used to connect to the LAN (it showed that wired network was connected) but there was no Internet access. I restarted my machine with the network cable plugged in. This lead to an error displaying `Device not configured`. I fixed this by reading a question online.

Now my machine connects to the LAN with no Internet access. The network works fine on Windows.

```
ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:ca:3a:d7:67:f5  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2818 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:197 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:210007 (210.0 KB)  TX bytes:11502 (11.5 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1076 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1076 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:105216 (105.2 KB)  TX bytes:105216 (105.2 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:6c:66:86:81:c0  
          inet addr:192.168.150.107  Bcast:192.168.150.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::626c:66ff:fe86:81c0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:18694 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12035 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:22755906 (22.7 MB)  TX bytes:1269060 (1.2 MB)



 NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0  [NTCC] --------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            iwlwifi
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        60:6C:66:86:81:C0

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           72 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    Pln_Omini_1:     Infra, D4:CA:6D:9D:21:09, Freq 2447 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 25
    *NTCC:           Infra, FE:85:DE:78:5C:91, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 80 WPA2
    Connectify-me:   Infra, 18:3D:A2:4A:BF:3D, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 92 WPA2
    IRL-BITS:        Infra, 84:1B:5E:3A:33:86, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 19 WPA2
    AndroidAP:       Infra, 20:02:AF:3B:91:84, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 89 WPA2
    plasmodium:      Infra, C0:3F:0E:EB:87:48, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 20 WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.150.107
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.150.1

    DNS:             192.168.150.1


- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        B8:CA:3A:D7:67:F5

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the results of: nm-tool

Comment: @chili555 can you please guide me what command to run in the terminal. Thanks sorry I am a n00b

Comment: Yes. Please run this command in the terminal: nm-tool. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: @chili555 done mate

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be connected by wireless but using the tricky driver iwlwifi. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" >> /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
exit
```

Reboot and let us hear your report.

Comment: still the same situation.Any other test you want me to do?

Comment: can we please communicate on chat? I feel that would help faster. Also we can post the solution so other people can have a look. @chili555

Comment: Sure. Do you have a chat started?